# Convergence of Newton's method (exercice)

Tags: newton-raphson

I am doing an exercice to prove the convergence of the [Newton's Method](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Newton%27s_method).
Let f b an holomorphic function on a simply connected space. 
$\ x^* \epsilon         \space \Omega, \space f(x^*) = 0 \space $and $\ \space f'(x^*)\neq 0 $. 
$\ g = id - \frac{f}{f'} $ with id the identity function.

I proved that $\ g'(x^*) = 0 $
Now I have ton conclude that there exist a circle centered in $\ x^* $  with a radius $\ \alpha \neq 0$ such as $\ |g'(z)| < \epsilon $. (with $\ \epsilon < 1 $)

 I don't know where to begin.

Comment: Doesn't this just follow from the fact that $g'(x*) = 0$ and $g'$ is continuous since $g$ is holomorphic (and thus $g'$ is holomorphic)?????

Comment: I don't understand the link between that and the circle

Comment: understand continuity better - that's all I can tell you.

Comment: I don't understand about the 1. Why is it the unit circle? How to prove that g'(z) is bounded by 1?